# WPF Examples using Datatable and MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, datatable, caliburn.micro

I am trying to load a RadGridView with datatable but dosn't seems to work. I am able to get the data from the Database and is stored in the Datatable "sampleResult" but getting displayed. What am I doing wrong.

```
public  class ResultViewModel
{

    private DataTable _sampleResult;
    public DataTable sampleResult
    {
        set
        {
            _sampleResult = value;
        }
        get { return _sampleResult; }
    }
    public  ResultViewModel()
    {
        Task.WhenAll(loadData(""));
    }

    ResulDataService rs = new ResulDataService();


    public async Task loadData(string sql)
    {
        sampleResult = null;
        sampleResult = await rs.LoadFinquoteResultsAsync();

    }
}
```

XAML is as follows

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="sampleResult" GroupRenderMode="Flat"
                         RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                         CanUserFreezeColumns="True"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding sampleResult}"
                         LeftFrozenColumnCount="5"
                         ShowSearchPanel="True">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                   <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn x:Name="Check" Header="Select" > 
            </telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn>   
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: Without a notification the UI will not update the binding. Read about [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: There are some more issues with your ViewModel ... but start with the notification first